# How can I use @Query result in SDN3?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, sdn

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j 3.0.0 in my web site.

I have some problem doing develope. 
I use @Query Annontation in @NodeEntity model class.

```
@Query(value = "START a=node({self}) MATCH (a)<-[:`COMMENT_TO`]-(b) RETURN b ORDER BY    b.createdAt DESC")
private Set<BaseComment> sortedComments;
```

and I try to use this result...then sortedComments type was SpringEndResult.
How can i use this result to Set ?

and can I use this in .jsp? 
when I using sortedComments in jsp with JSTL(c:foreach).
I met SpringEndResult doesn't have property exception.

I'm not english native. 
Thanks for your response. :)

```
@Test
public void getList() {
    List<SimpleArticle> articles = articleService.getAll(0, 10).getContent();
    for (SimpleArticle simpleArticle : articles) {
        Set<BaseComment> comments = simpleArticle.getSortedComments();
        for (BaseComment baseComment : comments) {
            log.info(baseComment);
        }
    }
}
```

And I met

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringEndResult cannot be cast to kr.carcare.model.bbs.BaseComment
```

This is my domain class

```
public class SimpleArticle extends BaseArticle {

@RelatedTo(type = "COMMENT_TO", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
@Fetch
private Set<BaseComment> comments;

@Query("START a=node({self}) MATCH (a)<-[:`COMMENT_TO`]-(b) RETURN b ORDER BY b.createdAt DESC")
private Set<BaseComment> sortedComments;
```

Comment: Interesting, it should actually be a Set. Can you raise a JIRA issue for this? Best with a failing unit-test.

Comment: Hi Michael. I write this at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-474.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SpringEndResult's "as" method and feed it something like Set.class (or something similar that implements Iterable).

I can't recall if that's the exact syntax, but, the "as" method takes a class parameter that extends Iterable, where R is the template type; in your case, R is BaseComment.

Comment: sortedComments.as(Set.class)

Comment: Can I get the sample code? 
sortedComments type is Set, don't have .as() method.

Comment: Changed "sortedComments"' type to "SpringEndResult" instead of a Set, and then use that result's "as" method to convert the result into a set.  Make sense?

Comment: Change*, not changed.  Sorry.

Comment: Changed "EndResult" and I met java.util.NoSuchElementException: More than one element in org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.QueryResultBuilder$1$1@59a69d87.

Comment: Can you update your original post with the new code and point out the line that's throwing the exception?

Comment: Or, try switching to Iterable<BaseComment> sortedComments;  ...then using IteratorUtil.asSet(sortedComments); once you have the results in sortedComments.